# comfyui Dwpose error unnecessarily trying to connect to hugging face

Tags: python, huggingface-hub

I have the 2 models shown in the screen shot but for some reason comfyui dwpose node does not find them despite the fact that they are shown in the drop downs. Since I have the files already, I don't understand why the system is trying to connect to huggingface (which for some strange reason is not accessible via the python code despite the fact that I have no problem downloading them from huggingface manually) which is unnecessary. Can someone suggest how to bypass the part of the code in  the python file (i think its util.py in the root of this folder S:\Program Files\ComfyUI\ComfyUI\custom_nodes\comfyui_controlnet_aux ) that is trying to download from huggingface and instead have it just use the local files that I already have. Its seem like poor design that there isn't an easy way to indicate that the code should look locally first instead of going to hugging face.
any help appreciated.
[image]

I have the actual models and I placed them in the root and also in the onnx models folder of comfy but dwpose is not seeing them. I'm not interested in solving the huggingface connection issue. I just want to know how to force the system to use the files that i already downloaded from huggingface manaully which makes downloading the files via huggingface_hub a moot point.